# convergence of $\large \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to determine if the underneath integral converges or not.

$\large \int_1^{+\infty}  \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx$

> I know that in the interval [1, $+\infty$)  the enqualities:

$ \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1+x}} \leq  \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$  holds.

> so if  $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}} dx$  converges then   so does   $\large \int_1^{+\infty}  \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx$

Does my anlysis hold?

Comment: You inequalities are incorrect. Choose say $x=8$. Then you say $\ln 8\le \frac 13\ln 8$.

Comment: You are right.  i had to keep just second part of the inequality.  I will update it . Thanks

Comment: @SAM.Am, use '\ln' because $\ln$ is a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_2^{\infty} \frac {ln x} {\sqrt {1+x}} dx\geq \ln 2 \int_2^{\infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt {1+x}} dx>\ln 2 \int_2^{\infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt {2 x}}=\infty$ so the integral is divergent.

Comment: can you exlpain, please, , why did you change the integration bornes from 1 to $+\infty $ to 2 $+\infty$

Comment: If the integral from $1$ to $\infty$ converges then the integral from $a$ to $\infty$ must also converge for every $a \in (1,\infty)$.  @SAM.Am

Answer (score 2):

$$\large \int_2^{+\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx            \ge \frac 12\large \int_2^{+\infty} \frac{dx}x =\infty $$
The integral diverges.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{\beta}}<\infty$$ if $\beta>1$ diverges if $\beta<1$, because in your case $\beta=1/2<1$.
Hence the given integral will diverge like $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{0.99}}$$

Comment: What on earth are you suggesting?